# Syncing code on static site between multiple html pages?

Tags: github-pages

I have a large website with several consistent text, like the nav, contact, footer, etc. I was wondering how I could keep all of these consistent on my static website (hosted on github pages) by loading the code from another file or any other method, since currently I have to manually update everything and it takes a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github pages uses Jekyll as the underlying static site generator. You can break down your site into multiple smaller html pages that can be included into a main layout.

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/

> The include tag allows you to include the content from another file
> stored in the _includes folder:
>
> ```
> {% include footer.html %}
> ```
>
> Jekyll will look for the referenced file (in this case, footer.html)
> in the _includes directory at the root of your source directory and
> insert its contents.

Read the documentation on this and you can easily find repeated text/html and replace them with includes.

If you're not already, this site has instructions so you can run jekyll locally to verify changes before pushing the changes to Github.

Comment: If I add css classes to it, would those be able to work from the style.css called from the html file it was generated into?

Comment: @theAnshulGupta Read the documentation on SASS: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/